# How to add 'View all site contents link' using Powershell/JQuery

Tags: jquery, powershell, sharepoint

We are migrating few site collections from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint online,

While POC we saw that 'View All site contents' link is removed and is not visible to users.

Is there any way to add the 'View All site contents' link explicitly using PowerShell or JQuery.

Also, i saw that we can add the link using , can we add this to the existing menu on the top right corner.

Thanks in advance

Paru

Comment: None answered this question, ????

Comment: We are using ShareGate to migrate the sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work for Sharegate. One of our dev guys created this PowerShell script to help you out!

First, can you install SharePoint Online Management Shell? https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Then, run the following PowerShell script (modify your site, login and password):

```
# Begin the process
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$loadInfo3 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles")

# Change to match your tenant information
$webUrl = "<your-site-url>" 
$username = "<your-admin-login>"
$password = "<your-admin-password>"

$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePass)

# Get the collection of navigation nodes from the quick launch bar
$web = $ctx.Web
$quickLaunch = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch

# Add a new navigation node
$navNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$navNode.AsLastNode = $true
$navNode.Title = "Site Contents"
$navNode.Url = $web.Url + "_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"
$navNode.IsExternal = $false

$ctx.Load($quickLaunchColl.Add($navNode))
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-Host "Done!"
```

Let me know how this works!

Comment: Thank you so much for help, i will run this script asap and let you know the result. 
In the mean time i would like to know if this problem a usual thing while migrating sites thru Sharegate? the 'Site content' link dissapears from the Quick launch after the migration.

Comment: The reason for this is because the link wasn't in the navigation in versions 2007 & 2010, but it was in the SharePoint layout. As of 2013 certain site templates don't even have it in their layout. So that's probably what's going on... it appears in the navigation but it's not really a navigation element. Make sense?

Comment: yes it does makes sense, thank you for the reply and the script works absolutely fine, just i have to add a condition to it to check if the link is already present then script should not add a new link as it make it redundant then.

Thanks again!!